# Using SQL variable on similar named columns in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I am trying to compare names on two different tables but I want the user to define what name column they want to search for (Forename, Middle name, Surname).

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(50)
SET @Col = 'Surname'

SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.@Col, tbl2.ID, tbl2.@Col
FROM table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2
ON tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID
```

Is something like this even possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

If more information is needed please ask.

Comment: You cannot parameterize identifiers (such as column names) in a query.  You would need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this:

```
DECLARE @Col VARCHAR(50);  -- should use sysname
SET @Col = 'Surname';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.@Col, tbl2.ID, tbl2.@Col
FROM table1 tbl1 INNER JOIN
     table2 tbl2
     ON tbl2.ID = tbl1.ID';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@Col', @Col);  -- should really use [QUOTENAME()][1]

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is a must in my opinion.